# Elm WebSocket with binary data

Tags: sockets, elm

I need to use sockets with binary data, so I have copied Evan's library into my source and hacked the native code to read

```
 socket.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        console.log("** onmessage");

        try {
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }

        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(event) {
            // ArrayBuffer
            let record = msgpack.decode(new Uint8Array(event.target.result));
            let recordString = JSON.stringify(record.NewRecords[0].Record);
            _elm_lang$core$Native_Scheduler.rawSpawn(A2(settings.onMessage, socket, recordString));
        });
    });
```

I have three issues error:

- I get less callbacks in Elm than `** onmessage` logs
- for larger messages, I get a fraction of the `** onmessage` logs that I expect
- I don't get any subsequent messages

For the first, I thought that my closure above would make a new filereader instance each time there was a message (and indeed I get no errors about filereader being busy). Code like this worked fine when I built some simple js socket handling code that connected to a port.

For the second, it looks as though the socket is losing track of messages altogether. I'm wondering whether there is an issue with having `_elm_lang$core$Native_Scheduler.rawSpawn(A2(settings.onMessage, socket, recordString));` in a new closure, leading to some sort of race condition on the value of `socket`?

**Update**
Using the dev console I can see that the first time I hit the rawSpawn line, `socket.readyState == 1` (open) but thereafter `socket.readyState == 3` (i.e. closed). I do not have any code that closes it.

Comment: Is the `FileReader` object created in the right place? Maybe it should be created when a connection is opened, and zeroed after each complete message.

Comment: i think it is something to do with the socket - see my update